# How to assign multiple resource in task for different duration?

Tags: ms-project

For example I have an activity “Support execution” and it’s duration for 12 hours.
To execute this task I need resource X1, B1, C1 & D1.
X1 required  from the start of activity till end means 12 hours.
B1 required after Two hours of starting activity for 4hours only.
C1 required after 5 hours till end.
D1 required in last 2 hours only.

Kindly let me know how I can put lag or schedule each for specific time and for specific duration???

Answer (score 1):

1. Create the task with a duration of 12h.  (Default fixed-units type is ok.)
2. Assign resources x1, b1, c1, d1.
3. Open the Task Usage view in the bottom pane.  Insert the Assignment Delay column.
4. For b2, c1, and d1 assignments, revise the Work and Assignment Delay values to match your requirements.